# Using with_context in super call turns into infinite call in odoo

Tags: odoo, odoo-8

In odoo context dictionary is frozen so no one can update it,
for that one solution is also available is calling method using `with_context`.

```
ctx = self.env.context.copy()
ctx.update({'additional_parameter' : value})
self.with_context(ctx).methodname()
```

but when we use the same pattern to call super method then result turns into the infinite call.

```
ctx = self.env.context.copy()
ctx.update({'additional_parameter' : value})
super(product_product, self).with_context(ctx).create(vals)
```

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: In which method you are writing this Code ? and do you have any code related to additional_parameter in the methodname ?

Comment: you can do it in any method in any model in which you call super method using with_context it will turns to infinite call and you will get message max recursion depth  ....!!!!!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I think you should try something like this at respective line:

```
super(product_product, self.with_context(ctx)).create(vals)
```